# Do spell and pronounce mean the same?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

I am seeing many reels on Instagram where they ask a person "Can you spell Y, E, S". The person says "Yes". Then they ask him "Can you spell E, Y, E, S". The person says "E-Yes" instead of "Eyes".

Until today I thought that they should be using "pronounce" instead of "spell". Isn't spell the opposite? You ask a person how you spell "Yes" and they would answer Y, E, S.

I saw so many reels from English speaking countries and now I am terribly confused if I don't understand what spell means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are absolutely correct.**

["Spell" means to list the letters in a word](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/spell). The correct word for what is being done here is "pronounce".

However "pronounce" is a long and unfamiliar word for those not fluent in English, and "spell" is an easy one. Since English is widely used as a second language, and by others without a huge vocabulary, it is unsurprising that a simple word is substituted for a complex one where the meaning can be deduced.

Comment: They should ask "What does Y-E-S spell?"

Comment: Do you know that this was from a non-native speaker? I wouldn't be surprised if it was just a native speaker who mixed them up.

Comment: @alphabet Yes, that's quite likely.